# Can't open DWG file in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis-3, dwg

I'm trying to import a DWG file into QGIS. I tried with both 3.16 and 3.4 versions. Not able to open in either version. Attached is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Downloaded a sample DWG from internet. Even the sample file also throwing the same error.

[image]

Comment: Try QGIS>Project>Import/Export>Import Layers from DWG/DXF

Comment: Tried. Still throwing error. I've edited the question. Downloaded a sample file from internet. But still getting the same error

Answer (score 5):

Its probably the version of the DWG - QGIS doesn't like newer versions of CAD files.

Your best bet is to try and save it as an older DWG/DXF file.

Comment: File is in 2013 format. There should not be any problem with this version rite.

I've edited the question. Downloaded a sample file from internet. But still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

OK. "Target Package" should be a new gpkg. I tried to save the dwg in an already existing gpkg. Now i can able to load the dwg